# Teamcity - Monitoring a specific folder as a VCS trigger

Tags: git, teamcity

We are moving to a monolithic repository for a project which means that when a commit occurs, on team city we need to determine which build to kick off.

Consider the following repo:

```
/
  a/
  b/
```

We currently have builds per sub-project that need to trigger when commits

In VCS triggers, we can create a VCS trigger rule, which "seems" to work however I have the following questions:

1. if I commit a change to folder `b`, through a trigger rule I can make only the builds for `b` kick off.  However, the builds for `a` show pending changes that are unrelated.
2. Is this approach sensible long term?  Are there any unintended gotchas that occur?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to see unrelated pending changes, consider using checkout rules. If you set checkout rules to +:a TeamCity will show changes under "a" directory only. But be aware that with such checkout rules only directory "a" will appear in agent checkout directory.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. If you use trigger rules in the VCS trigger, this just means whether a build is kicked off automatically if there is anything checked in. So yes, the pending changes will of course be shown and if you have a dependency from one build configuration to another, a new build will be triggered even if there are only "unrelated" changes. But I don't think you will have any drawbacks.

Comment: I feel the "pending change" will be a drawback as to anyone looking it's as if something related hasn't built.  Over the course of a project, that number is going to be large.

Comment: Well, you could set up an additional nightly trigger, so that at least nightly the projects are built and the pending changes count stays low.

Comment: Agreed, makes sense.